# Disable caching of a specific exploded war folder in JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, war

I would like to disable caching on a specific exploded war folder deployed to JBoss 4.2.3. The reason is that content is added to this folder about every 15 seconds by an external process, and with caching enabled this results in several million copies and eventually fills up the drive.

Is there a way to disable caching on this specific folder?

Comment: You could purge the old cache from that external process as a part of update every 15 seconds.

Comment: That is certainly a possibility. I am hoping for a solution that is closer to JBoss itself because I don't want another process messing around with anything JBoss manages internally.